# Changing application that processes Event Hub stream results in starting from epoch 0, why?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have two Function apps that are processing an Event Hub, they're both using the same consumer group.

Only one function in each Function app actually interacts with the Event Hub.

I've disabled App1's function that interacts with the Event Hub and enabled App2's function. This means that the functions that interact with the Event Hub in each Function app never run at the same time.

What I find though, is that upon disabling App1, and enabling App2's function, App2 will always read from epoch 0 of the Event Hub. This means I re-process a large chunk of data every time I switch between App1 and App2's function.

How do I get them to share the state so that they're both running from a shared epoch? (which I know is recorded in the Event Hub's attached storage).

I'm wondering if I need to completely shut down App1 - not just disable the function?
Sounds like there's a lease problem, but I don't quite understand it.

And for the record - I will not be switching between these Function Apps in the future, App2 will replace App1, but I can't have it re-processing data. (Though the data is idempotent, it would result in a large hit to traffic and performance, along with storage costs).

EDIT:
Previous app was Functions 1.x and .Net Framework. New app is Functions 4.x and .Net 6. So lots of changes, but same functionality implemented.

Comment: Have you checked the attached Storage account to see what data it is storing for the checkpoints? I wonder if those are somehow separated between the two Function apps. I checked a .NET 6 + Functions v4 app's data and there definitely is nothing that would lock it to a specific Function app.. It stores blobs per partition and keeps the offsets in blob metadata. Not sure if the stored data model has changed from older .NET FX -> .NET 6.

Comment: So the storage being used is the same, and the blobs generated look very similar - however, with the .Net 6 app, the "Owner" and "Token" fields are blank. With the Framework app, those fields are filled in with Guids.
It also seems that the Framework app can continue from where the .Net 6 app left off, but not the opposite way.

Comment: Ok, so i was wrong. The storage being used is different. They have the same folder structure until the level the Framework app (App1) has it's blobs on. At that point, the .net  app (App2) has two folders: Checkpoint & Ownership.
Those folders each have blobs in, but every blob is empty(!), which i've checked by downloading. (They are also 0 bytes)
This was all in the "azure-webjobs-eventhub" container for both.

So - in short, i've no idea how the .Net 6 app (App2) is actually storing its data to figure out where in the event hub stream it actually is... And this is not compatible at all.

Comment: Correct. The blobs were empty in my case as well. The data was in the blob metadata.

Comment: Oh, you're right, i completely missed that!
I wonder if this means i can basically craft the scenario where the new functions app will take over by modifying those...  I will experiment tomorrow!

Comment: What versions of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs` package are referenced by each app?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.EventHubs 3.0.1
vs
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventHubs 5.1.0

To migrate to the later Functions App, you have to use the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.* packages.

Comment: That explains things a bit.   Versions prior to v5.0.0 used a legacy version of the SDK which write checkpoint and ownership content to the blob.   Starting in v5, the current generation package is used, which uses blob metadata.    The data is not shared between v3 and v5, and they won't coordinate ownership or consume the same checkpoint data.    When v5 does not find a checkpoint in the new format, it will read the old format and convert it - but this is a one-way upgrade.

Comment: @juunas I tested this today. I stopped the functions apps, copied over the epoch & offset values from the old blobs into the metadata on the new blobs. I then started the new functions app, which used the metadata to start it's processing with no data lost. If you provide it as an answer here i will accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the reason that the checkpoints were not used was that the way the Functions stored information about checkpoints was different.

The older SDK stores the epoch and offset inside the blob content, while the newer one uses blob metadata.
Putting those values in metadata before starting the newer function seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: To be clear, the fields are "offset" and "sequencenumber". The others can be ignored, as can the "ownership" folder entirely.